# Chaging default theme, and adding styles to form componants

Tags: css, extjs4, sass, extjs4.1

I have few questions on styles (Themes). Presently i get a blue colored theme in all my window and panels. I want to change this to Pink. How can i do that ?

I read about `swapStyleSheet( String id, String url) : Void` but, i am not sure how to use it.

2.) I also need to know how to change the colors of labels/form panels etc, I want all the styles to be on 1 page, rather than adding it as an attribute in labels/form panels. (eg: `fieldStyle: 'background-color: #ddd; background-image: none;'`)

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not created a custom theme, there is a themeing guide located here: http://www.sencha.com/learn/theming/ that will give you very powerful tools to create your theme instead of styling individual components.